# Adding additional digits to Twilio hello monkey

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I attempted to add a new digit to the Twilio.com hello monkey script. When I press 1, 2 or 0 it restarts, it doesn't navigate to the voicemail or direct the call.

Here's my code:

Step 1

```
<?php
// now greet the caller
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>   
    <Gather numDigits="1" action="handle.php" method="POST">
        <Play>http://morxmedia.com/phone/main.mp3</Play>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Step 2

```
<?php

    // if the caller pressed anything but 1 or 2 send them back
    if($_REQUEST['Digits'] != '1' and $_REQUEST['Digits'] != '2' and $_REQUEST['Digits'] != '0') {
        header("Location: step1.php");
        die;
    }

    // otherwise, if 1 was pressed we Dial 3105551212. If 2 
    // we make an audio recording up to 30 seconds long.
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
<?php if ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '1') { ?>
    <Dial>+13105551212</Dial>
    <Say>The call failed or the remote party hung up.  Goodbye.</Say>
<?php } elseif ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '2') { ?>
    <Play>http://morxmedia.com/phone/tech-support.mp3</Play>
    <Record maxLength="30" action="aftervm.php" />
<?php } elseif ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '0') { ?>
    <Dial>+13105551212</Dial>
    <Say>The call failed or the remote party hung up.  Goodbye.</Say>
<?php } ?>
</Response>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you verify that the problem is with adding the additional digit to the hello monkey script? Does it work fine when you run the script without the additional digit? Kevin

Comment: Maybe try echoing $_REQUEST and $_REQUEST['Digits'] onto the page to see what the values are...

Comment: @KevinBurke The original script works, as soon as I apply my MP3 file and the extra digit it messes up. However, I have an additional Twilio account that I setup that has additional digits that works fine. I honestly don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I have discovered that if I remove the main.mp3 and replace it with a <Play> it works fine... I am researching to see if Twilio has a size limit on the mp3 files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a full URL for the action:

```
<Gather numDigits="1" action="handle.php" method="POST">
```

It seems that using a full URL in the play tag is causing Twilio to treat `handle.php` as `http://morxmedia.com/phone/handle.php` (which, at this moment, does not exist).

When I ran your sample code, I got an application error (because `handle.php` did not exist). My guess is that you have the 'fallback' URL set to the main menu, and that's what's causing the confusion.

**Update**: It should be noted that only using `http://morxmedia.com/phone/tech-support.mp3` causes the odd reset of relative paths, using the hello monkey mp3 file does not. Perhaps some odd server configuration is confusing the Twilio HTTP client (causing the path issue, and the continued requesting of `step1.php`).

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim!
I changed all the action link and the header link to http://morxmedia.com/phone/[file]
And it still restarts as soon as any digit is pressed.

Comment: @StephenHarman Do those files exist? When I visit `http://morxmedia.com/phone/handle.php` I get a 'not found' page.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I was tinkering with it and didn't realize. It should be there now. And the main file is http://morxmedia.com/phone/start.php

Comment: @StephenHarman Once I used full URLs (so it wasn't pointing to a missing file) your code worked on my server. Are you getting anything in the twilio debugger?

Comment: nope, no errors what so ever, that is what is so confusing, are you using my mp3 files as well?

Comment: @StephenHarman Yeah, when I used your mp3 file it caused the redirect to your server (which at the time, didn't have the `handle.php` file). It still actually does that (redirects to your server), which it doesn't do with the hello monkey mp3 file. Everything works fine when I run it locally, but when it hits your server weird things happen. Any odd headers/caching/redirects/rewrites going on?

Comment: I'm hosted on HostGator. I actually have several accounts with them and I tested the same configuration on another one and same thing happens. However, I have a different Twilio system on the separate one that works perfectly fine and it has just about the same setup (just a modified hello monkey). Could the issue be in the MP3 file?

Comment: @StephenHarman It's either the server/site or the mp3 - have you used the same file on another server? Does that work?

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so long. So I spent some time talking with HostGator, (my sever host) and apparently I had 777 the directory and they don't support that. Thank you for your time.